# Laravel 5.4 User Null With React Fetch

Tags: php, laravel, reactjs

**Route (web.php)**

```
Route::get('user', function () {
    $user=Auth::user();
    return response(['user_id'=>$user->id],200);
});
```

React.js `fetch()`

```
fetch('/user')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(json => {
                console.log(json);
            });
```

When visiting `/user` in a browser:

```
{"user_id":1}
```

When running the `fetch()` method:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

This is because `$user=Auth::user();` is returning `null`.

I know this is not a `csrf` issue because returning static content (such as `user_id=>1` ) works fine with the fetch method.

Here are the cookies being sent with the request:

[image]

Whats stopping the user session from working? Been messing with this for hours.

Comment: Have you tried creating a controller to do this from, instead of doing it in the route file? Atleast just to see what it returns.

Edit: Also it could be a middleware issue.. I had kinda the same problem in the 5.2 laravel version as long time ago

Comment: are you sure that `fetch()` is not an API call? because based from my findings, API is stateless, thus, it is normal that `Auth::user()` returns null. Have you tried using a normal AJAX request? Sorry, I'm not familiar with *reactjs*.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that my picture shows cookies being *returned*, not sent.

Changed `fetch()` code to this and it worked:

```
    fetch('/user',{
        credentials: 'include' //Includes cookies
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
            console.log(json);
        });
```